# Mathematical Operations in a SQL UPDATE query using MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to add some amount to existing values in MySQL with this way but its not working for me, instead it is changing all values to zero.

```
UPDATE `fares` 
SET `fare`='`fare` + 70' 
WHERE `season_start`='2015-08-22' 
    AND `season_end`='2015-12-09' 
    AND  `ticket_class`='Y/Y' 
    AND `fare_type`='return' 
    AND `deptsub_code`='LHR' 
    AND `dest_code`='ASM'
```

I want to add 70 to all values. My column type is `smallint(5)`

Please suggest any other way or let me know where the error is?

Comment: You are using single quotes where you shouldn't have them (in the `set`).  I'm voting to close as this is a simple typographical error.

Comment: `SET fare = fare + 70` remove the quotes. voted to close by a simple typographical error too

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the apostrophes in the `SET` expression i.e.

```
UPDATE `fares` SET `fare`=`fare` + 70
```

rather than

```
UPDATE `fares` SET `fare`='`fare` + 70'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE `fares` SET `fare`=`fare` + 70 WHERE `season_start`='2015-08-22' AND `season_end`='2015-12-09' AND  `ticket_class`='Y/Y' AND `fare_type`='return' AND `deptsub_code`='LHR' AND `dest_code`='ASM'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just done it with this way and its working for me:

```
UPDATE `fares` SET `fare`=(`fare` + 70) WHERE `season_start`='2015-08-22' AND `season_end`='2015-12-09' AND  `ticket_class`='Y/Y' AND `fare_type`='return' AND `deptsub_code`='LHR'
```

Anyway Thanks